# Hibernate - Entity referencing itself through a join table with an additional column

Tags: hibernate, jpa, hibernate-annotations

I have an annotated Entity called Part. It consists of an "id" and a few other variables. I have another table called "bomdefinitions". This table has three columns (qty, parent, target) (I understand target is a stupid name but I can't change it as the database already exists). The idea is a Part can be made up of many other parts, and can also be used in many other parts, and the table "bomdefinitions" says what parent has what "target"s associated with it and how many are used by it.

The problem is, if I comment out one of the OneToMany relationships in Part.java and leave the other, it works fine, but if I have them both in my code, trying to access either of them results in an infinite loop of Hibernate queries.

I can find examples of mapping an entity to itself, examples of mapping an entity using a join table with extra columns, and examples of various ways to do the annotations, but nothing doing all of that within a single application, and the individual examples I can find don't seem to be helping here.

Anyone with more experience in Hibernate have any ideas as to what I am doing wrong?

Edit (this code causes the infinite loop):

```
getHibernateTemplate().get(Part.class, id).getParentBomDefinitions();
```

And here is the query in the Output -
It starts with:

```
Hibernate: select part0_.id as id0_3_, childbomde1_.target as target0_5_, childbomde1_.parent as parent5_, childbomde1_.target as target5_, childbomde1_.parent as parent4_0_, childbomde1_.target as target4_0_, childbomde1_.qty as qty4_0_, part2_.id as id0_1_ from parts part0_ left outer join bomdefinitions childbomde1_ on part0_.id=childbomde1_.target left outer join parts part2_ on childbomde1_.parent=part2_.id
Hibernate: select parentbomd0_.parent as parent0_2_, parentbomd0_.parent as parent2_, parentbomd0_.target as target2_, parentbomd0_.parent as parent4_1_, parentbomd0_.target as target4_1_, parentbomd0_.qty as qty4_1_, part1_.id as id0_0_ from bomdefinitions parentbomd0_ left outer join parts part1_ on parentbomd0_.target=part1_.id where parentbomd0_.parent=?
```

Then these 2 queries repeat indefinitely:

```
Hibernate: select parentbomd0_.parent as parent0_2_, parentbomd0_.parent as parent2_, parentbomd0_.target as target2_, parentbomd0_.parent as parent4_1_, parentbomd0_.target as target4_1_, parentbomd0_.qty as qty4_1_, part1_.id as id0_0_ from bomdefinitions parentbomd0_ left outer join parts part1_ on parentbomd0_.target=part1_.id where parentbomd0_.parent=?
Hibernate: select childbomde0_.target as target0_2_, childbomde0_.parent as parent2_, childbomde0_.target as target2_, childbomde0_.parent as parent4_1_, childbomde0_.target as target4_1_, childbomde0_.qty as qty4_1_, part1_.id as id0_0_ from bomdefinitions childbomde0_ left outer join parts part1_ on childbomde0_.parent=part1_.id where childbomde0_.target=?
```

BomDefinition.java (pretty much taken out of "Java Persistence with Hibernate")

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "bomdefinitions")
public class BomDefinition {

@Embeddable
public static class Id implements Serializable {

    @Column(name = "target")
    private String targetId;

    @Column(name = "parent")
    private String parentId;

    public Id() {}
    public Id(String targetId, String parentId) {
        this.targetId = targetId;
        this.parentId = parentId;
    }
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (o != null && o instanceof Id) {
            Id that = (Id) o;
            return this.targetId.equals(that.targetId) && this.parentId.equals(that.parentId);
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    public int hashCode() {
        return targetId.hashCode() + parentId.hashCode();
    }
}

@EmbeddedId
private Id id = new Id();

@Column(name = "qty")
private String quantity;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "parent",
            insertable = false,
            updatable = false)
private Part parent;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "target",
            insertable = false,
            updatable = false)
private Part child;

public BomDefinition() {}

public BomDefinition(String quantity, Part parent, Part child) {
    this.quantity = quantity;
    this.parent = parent;
    this.child = child;

    this.id.parentId = parent.getId();
    this.id.targetId = child.getId();
}

// Getters and Setters
}
```

Part.java:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="parts", uniqueConstraints = {@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"id"})})
public class Part implements Serializable {

protected final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(getClass());

private String id;
// *** other variables ***

public Part() {}

public Part(String id, /* other variables */) {
    this.id = id;
    // *** other variables ***
}

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
public String getId() {
    return this.id;
}
public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

private Set parentBomDefinitions = new HashSet(0);
private Set childBomDefinitions = new HashSet(0);

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent",
            targetEntity = BomDefinition.class,
            cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE},
            fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
public Set getParentBomDefinitions() {
    return parentBomDefinitions;
}
public void setParentBomDefinitions(Set<BomDefinition> parentBomDefinitions) {
    this.parentBomDefinitions = parentBomDefinitions;
}

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "child",       // target?
            targetEntity = BomDefinition.class,
            cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE},
            fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
public Set getChildBomDefinitions() {
    return childBomDefinitions;
}
public void setChildBomDefinitions(Set childBomDefinitions) {
    this.childBomDefinitions = childBomDefinitions;
}

}
```

Comment: What is the query fired in the infinite loop - could be due to some problem with the data - it is a graph with cycles not a tree.

Comment: Looking at the output again this morning, it would seem the problem lies in that each time it queries to get a child part, it queries that child part to get its parent and children, whose parent happens to be the original part, which it they queries to get its child, etc.  Something isn't configured right, but I haven't figured out what that is.

Comment: Remove the fetch=FetchType.EAGER on the OneToManyAssociation - at least the parentBOmDefinitions

Comment: I was using FetchType.EAGER to get around "failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: model.Part.parentBomDefinitions, no session or session was closed".  I can kind of see how setting that to lazy would keep it from actively searching through children for parents and parents for children.  Not sure how to get around the "failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: model.Part.parentBomDefinitions, no session or session was closed" error though, I have a hunch it is related to using HibernateTemplate and not managing my own transactions.

Comment: Using SessionFactory to manage my own session indeed allows me to get around the lazily initialize error. I would prefer not to manage my own transactions, but for something like this it looks like I might have to.  Will advise how it goes.

Comment: Hah, I've removed the FetchType.EAGER from my OneToMany's.  It works fine with 1 up without the lazy error. With both OneToMany's uncommented it does the original query fine, but then tries to start it's recursion again and gets shut down by a closed session with the "lazily initialize" error.  Say I call getParentBomDefintions(), it successfully gets all the definitions and I can access each of them and do anything I want with it, but after I return from the method using getParentBomDefinitions it calls getChildBomDefinitions on the same session which I've already closed. Any ideas from here?

Comment: I am assuming that you are using spring transaction management - if you are getting the lazy initialization error in the web layer then you can use the OpenSessionInViewFilter / Interceptor - that will keep the session from closing till the complete web request processing is complete.  If it is not a webapp - you will need to initialize all the associations needed by your code before the transaction ends - by using HibernateProxy.initialize method.